# How can I turn an image into a 2D array in React Native?

Tags: arrays, react-native, multidimensional-array

I am working on an ASCII art project in React Native. The user chooses an image (for example, `file://image.jpg`). I want to convert that image into a 2D array/list formatted like this:

```
[
  [{red: 40, green: 240, blue: 255},{red: 40, green: 240, blue: 255}...],
  [{red: 40, green: 240, blue: 255},{red: 40, green: 240, blue: 255}...],
  [{red: 40, green: 240, blue: 255},{red: 40, green: 240, blue: 255}...] 
]
```

How would I convert the image into a 2D array formatted like the one above?